# Creating Laravel Model dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

How can I create Laravel Model dynamically or without php artisan command?
Alongside creating the model dynamically, how to crate the table and the rows for it? 
I cannot be able to find the exact solution anywhere!

Thanks!

Comment: You can create the files manually, an modelling directly on code..

Comment: Please show us what you already have.

Comment: If by dynamically you mean by code. Just making sure you know you can call PHP artisan command programmatically with PHP. Artisan::call('command')

Comment: @shadyhossin : Artisan:call() is not working. Can you help me with the working command for create a model with Model name?

Comment: @MatheusReis Yes I can do it, but I want to create model and create table with rows in programmatic way.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek: 

public function index()
    {
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('make:model',['name'=>'Computer']);

        return Artisan::output();
    }

This is not working at all !